# Custom loss function in Keras to penalize false negatives

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, gradient-descent, loss-function

I am working on a medical dataset where I am trying to have as less false negatives as possible. A prediction of "disease when actually no disease" is okay for me but a prediction "no disease when actually a disease" is not. That is, I am okay with `FP` but not `FN`.

After doing some research, I found out ways like `Keeping higher learning rate for one class`, `using class weights`,`ensemble learning with specificity/sensitivity` etc.

I achieved the near desired result using class weights like `class_weight = {0 : 0.3,1: 0.7}` and then calling the `model.fit(class_weights=class_weight)`. This gave me very low FN but a pretty high FP. I am trying to reduce FP as much as possible keeping FN very low.

I am struggling to write a **custom loss function** using `Keras` which will help me to penalize the false negatives. Thanks for the help.

Comment: [Here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/33587/keras-custom-loss-function-as-true-negatives-by-true-negatives-plus-false-posit) you can find how to write a custom Keras loss function for specificity.

Answer (score 22):

I'll briefly introduce the concepts we're trying to tackle.

### Recall

*From **all** that were **positive**, how many did our model predict as positive?*

All that were positive = [image: positive]

What our model said were positive = [image: said positive]

[image: recall]

Since recall is inversely proportional to FN, improving it decreases FN.

### Specificity

*From **all** that were **negative**, how many did our model predict as negative?*

All that were negative = [image: negative]

What our model said were negative = [image: said negative]

[image: specificity]

Since specificity is inversely proportional to FP, improving it decreases FP.

In your next searches, or whatever classification-related activity you perform, knowing these is going to give you an extra edge in communication and understanding.

---

### A Solution

So. These two concepts, as you mas have figured out already, are opposites. This means that **increasing one is likely to decrease the other**.

Since you want **priority** on recall, but don't want to loose too much in specificity, you can combine both of those and attribute weights. Following what's clearly explained in [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/33587/keras-custom-loss-function-as-true-negatives-by-true-negatives-plus-false-posit):

```py
import numpy as np
import keras.backend as K

def binary_recall_specificity(y_true, y_pred, recall_weight, spec_weight):

    TN = np.logical_and(K.eval(y_true) == 0, K.eval(y_pred) == 0)
    TP = np.logical_and(K.eval(y_true) == 1, K.eval(y_pred) == 1)

    FP = np.logical_and(K.eval(y_true) == 0, K.eval(y_pred) == 1)
    FN = np.logical_and(K.eval(y_true) == 1, K.eval(y_pred) == 0)

    # Converted as Keras Tensors
    TN = K.sum(K.variable(TN))
    FP = K.sum(K.variable(FP))

    specificity = TN / (TN + FP + K.epsilon())
    recall = TP / (TP + FN + K.epsilon())

    return 1.0 - (recall_weight*recall + spec_weight*specificity)
```

Notice `recall_weight` and `spec_weight`? They're weights we're attributing to each of the metrics. For distribution convention, they should always add to `1.0`¹, e.g. `recall_weight=0.9`, `specificity_weight=0.1`. The intention here is for you to see what proportion best suits your needs.

But Keras' loss functions must only receive `(y_true, y_pred)` as arguments, so let's define a wrapper:

```py
# Our custom loss' wrapper
def custom_loss(recall_weight, spec_weight):

    def recall_spec_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return binary_recall_specificity(y_true, y_pred, recall_weight, spec_weight)

    # Returns the (y_true, y_pred) loss function
    return recall_spec_loss
```

And onto using it, we'd have

```py
# Build model, add layers, etc
model = my_model
# Getting our loss function for specific weights
loss = custom_loss(recall_weight=0.9, spec_weight=0.1)
# Compiling the model with such loss
model.compile(loss=loss)
```

¹ The weights, added, must total `1.0`, because in case both `recall=1.0` and `specificity=1.0` (the perfect score), the formula

[image: loss1]

Shall give us, for example,

[image: loss2]

Clearly, if we got the perfect score, we'd want our loss to equal 0.

Comment: Hi @julio, I tried to implement your solution, but it returns me the next error: `InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'dense_1_target' with dtype float and shape [?,?]`. Any idea of how to fix it? The first thing I changed in your code was to replace np.logical_and to tf.logical_and, because it only works with tensors. But I don't know how to change the other error... Thank you in advance!

Comment: @CristinaV Were you able to replicate it in TensorFlow 2 ? I am also getting the same error.

Comment: Tried your solution but got an error ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable:

Comment: I don't see how this can be used in training, given that the function `binary_recall_specificity` is not differentiable, and breaks backpropagation.

Comment: This function did not work for me at first because I got an error "AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'enable_eager_execution'". I was able to fix that by setting 'run_eagerly=True' in the compiler: model.compile(<stuff>, run_eagerly=True). However as pointed out by @AndreyKuehlkamp, this is not differentiable and broke the backpropagation during training. I dont think this is a useable loss function as is.

Comment: You can use the reparameterization trick to make this differentiable.