# Tensorflow: Custom loss function to encourage/restrict false positives/negatives

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am looking for a way to encourage/restrict false positives/negatives. I have not been able to find a solution, which I can get working - most likely due to my lack of experience.

I found this post: [Custom loss function in Keras to penalize false negatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52695913/custom-loss-function-in-keras-to-penalize-false-negatives) which pretty much has the same purpose, but I cannot get the answer to work.

First I kept on getting this error:

***AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_numpy'***

After some searching around I found that it could be solved with ***"model.run_eagerly = True"***, this though provides this error:

***No gradients provided for any variable***

I would like not to use ***"model.run_eagerly = True"*** given that I am not entirely sure what it does, but it quite obviously makes it so that I need to do something with calculating gradients. I have therefore altered the code, but keep getting the ***No gradients provided for any variable***.

I have made an example of this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense

from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

class Custom_loss_Class(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self, recall_weight = 0.5, spec_weight = 0.5, name="custom"):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.recall_weight = recall_weight
        self.spec_weight = spec_weight

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        y_pred = tf.math.round(y_pred)
        y_true = tf.math.round(y_true)

        TN = tf.dtypes.cast(tf.math.logical_and(tf.math.equal(y_true, 0), tf.math.equal(y_pred, 0)), tf.float32)
        TP = tf.dtypes.cast(tf.math.logical_and(tf.math.equal(y_true, 1), tf.math.equal(y_pred, 1)), tf.float32)

        FP = tf.dtypes.cast(tf.math.logical_and(tf.math.equal(y_true, 0), tf.math.equal(y_pred, 1)), tf.float32)
        FN = tf.dtypes.cast(tf.math.logical_and(tf.math.equal(y_true, 1), tf.math.equal(y_pred, 0)), tf.float32)

        TN = tf.reduce_sum(TN)
        TP = tf.reduce_sum(TP)

        FP = tf.reduce_sum(FP)
        FN = tf.reduce_sum(FN)

        specificity = TN / (TN + FP + K.epsilon())
        recall = TP / (TP + FN + K.epsilon())

        loss = tf.Variable(1- (self.recall_weight * recall + self.spec_weight * specificity))

        return loss

data = load_breast_cancer()

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(data.data, data.target, test_size=0.3)
N, D = X_train.shape

scalar = StandardScaler()
X_train = scalar.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scalar.transform(X_test)

i = Input(shape=(D,))
x = Dense(64, activation="relu")(i)
x = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)

model = Model(i, x)

model.compile(optimizer="adam", 
          loss=Custom_loss_Class(recall_weight=0.1, spec_weight=0.9), 
          metrics="accuracy")

r = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), epochs=10)
```

I am aware that I can use ***class_weight*** to give one class more weight, but that is not really what I want. In this example I would like to heavily restrict false negatives so a patient with cancer do not get a negative prediction, but at the same time not get too many false positives. It seems like a common use case and I therefore hope someone made a good function for it.

**Edit**:

I am aware that this most likely is due to my loss function not being differentiable, but I do not know how to change that so I get the described functionality.

Comment: I think it has something to do that your loss function seems to be non-differentiable. As suggested in this [github issue comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1511#issuecomment-250662169), the use of `round` function makes the function non-differentiable. Also, as @mrry pointed out in the [comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1511#issuecomment-196879229), try to run this basic sanity check

Comment: Yes that seem to be the issue. I have been aware that this could be the problem, I unfortunately just do not know how to solve it. Do you know how to get the result I describe?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's long time ago, but someone may have the same issue.
I had the same problem, and I found a solution by calculating

```
TP =  tf.reduce_sum(y_true * y_pred)
```

In image modelling, we don't have TN as we are restricted to the ground truth and the predicted image, so:

```
FN = tf.reduce_sum(y_true) - TP

FP = tf.reduce_sum(y_pred) - TP
```

and the,

```
specificity = TN / (TN + FP + K.epsilon())

recall = TP / (TP + FN + K.epsilon())
```